# Psalm and PHPStan unable to read Symfony entity string:class

Tags: php, symfony, entity, phpstan, psalm-php

I'm implementing PHPStan into my application and also testing Psalm for automatic fixes, however I'm unable to make them read entity class strings (with colon) fe:

```
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('MyApp:EntityClass');
```

turns into Psalm error:

```
ERROR: UndefinedClass - src/Controller/MyController.php:229:48 - Class, interface or enum named MyApp:EntityClass does not exist (see https://psalm.dev/019)
```

and in PHP Stan

```
  Line   src/Controller/MyController.php                                                                                                               
 ------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  229    Parameter #1 $className of method Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface::getRepository() expects class-string<MyApp:EntityClass>, string given.  
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Easiest way to fix this is to use \EntityClass::class instead of a string 'MyApp:EntityClass' however I would like to avoid that. Probable I need to use some annotation to make both tools interprete string correctly, but I have problems figuring out which one.
It would also be nice to have it avaialble globaly via entire app, and don't use annotation each time I call a class via string.
Currently I've just added this error to ignored ones but would like to know how to fix that.

Comment: Did you try the PHPStan extension for Doctrine? The link is this:
https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine

However, using `\EntityClass::class` is the best option.

Comment: "Easiest way to fix this is to use \EntityClass::class instead of a string 'MyApp:EntityClass' however I would like to avoid that."

why you want to avoid that? it's not the recommended way IIRC

Answer (score 0):

> Easiest way to fix this is to use \EntityClass::class instead of a string 'MyApp:EntityClass' however I would like to avoid that.

You already wrote the recommended answer. Using [shortname alias is deprecated since `doctrine/orm` v2.10](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.10.x/UPGRADE.md#deprecated-entity-namespace-aliases). It'll probably be removed in v3.0. You should consider upgrading.

That said, this *is* the only sustainable solution.

```php
$repository = $this->em->getRepository(EntityClass::class);
```

### Install phpstan/phpstan-doctrine

Using phpstan without phpstan-doctrine is not recommended (while interpreting types of a doctrine entity). Install the phpstan extension `phpstan/phpstan-doctrine` and [configure it](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine#configuration). It interpretes types of `QueryBuilder` and `Repository` inside your project; like `EntityManager::getReposiotry(EntityClass::class)`:

```bash
composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan-doctrine
```

```
# phpstan.neon
parameters:
    doctrine:
        objectManagerLoader: tests/object-manager.php
```

### Optional: automatic refactoring

That said, you really should update your code base. To ease that process, you could use [rector](https://getrector.com/) using the [`EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector`](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-doctrine/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#entityaliastoclassconstantreferencerector). Correctly configured, you're done in seconds.

```bash
composer require --dev rector/rector
```

```php
// rector.php

<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Doctrine\Rector\MethodCall\EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->phpstanConfig(__DIR__.'/phpstan.neon');

    $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector::class, [
        EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector::ALIASES_TO_NAMESPACES => [
            'MyApp' => 'App\Entity',
        ]
    ]);
};
```